# Remove specific words from sentences in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to remove negative words form sentence using bash script .

The negative words that i meant it :

```
[dull,boring,annoying,bad]
```

My file text `text.txt` contains this sentence :

```
These dull boring cards are part of a chaotic board game ,and bad for people
```

I'm using this script

```
array=( dull boring annoying bad  )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
cat $p  | sed -e 's/\<$i\>//g' 
done < my_text.txt
```

But I got the following wrong result:

```
These boring cards are part of a chaotic board game ,and bad for people
```

The correct output must be like this :

```
These cards are part of a chaotic board game ,and for people
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, assuming $p is existed file
Then used this Script

```
while read p 
do 
  echo $p | sed  -e 's/\<dull\>//g' | sed -e 's/\<boring\>//g' | sed -e 's/\<annoying\>//g'|sed -e 's/\<bad\>//g' > my_text.txt
  
 cat my_text.txt
 
done < my_text.txt
```

The output of this script :

```
These  cards are part of a chaotic board game ,and  for people
```

Or can use this script, You have to use double quotes, not single quotes to get variables expanded.

```
array=( dull boring annoying bad )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    sed -i -e "s/\<$i\>\s*//g" my_text.txt
done
```

The `sed -i` switch replace in line.
The `sed -e` to add the script to the commands to be executed.

To learn more about sed command you can used in your terminal `man sed`

Comment: Running multiple static `sed` scripts in a chain or a loop betrays a fundamental lack of `sed` understanding. It's a scripting language, after all, albeit a primitive one.

Comment: Yes, your comment is important and I have added another solution to the question.

Comment: Running `sed -i` repeatedly on the same file is even worse because you replace the same text over and over.

Comment: There is more than one solution to the question, and the solution that you have raised is also good, thanks for the important remarks that you provided to me .

Answer (score 4):

You want to run a single `sed` script, generated from the array.

```sh
printf 's/\\<%s\\>//g' "${array[@]}" |
sed -f - my_text.txt
```

If your `sed` does not accept `-f -` to read the script from standard input, you need to refactor a bit.

Similarly, `\<` and `\>` as word boundaries may not be supported by your `sed`; perhaps try `\b` in both places if you have a different dialect.

...or in the worst case switch to Perl if your `sed` is really spare. Though of course, maybe refactor out Bash altogether then, and do this entirely in Perl.

```sh
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $re = "\\b(" . join("|", qw(
    dull boring annoying bad  )) . ")\\b" }
    s/$re//go' my_text.txt
```